# Including .NET assemblies in a VB6 manifest?

Tags: c#, com, vb6, manifest

I am working on a vb6 project and want to create a manifest so no registering is required.

I use MMM (Make My Manifest) tool which scans your VB6 project for dll dependencies and generates the manifest.

However, the MMM does not include tlb files, and I have a Client.dll and Client.tlb written in .net that which has been exposed to COM and used in my VB6 program.

I don't to you use Regasm as it would be nice if no register to the registry is done.

I tried to generate a seperate manifest for the via the mt tool in command line,   'mt.exe -tlb:Client.tlb -dll:Client.dll -out:Client.manifest'

Then I thought I could merge the 2 manifest via: 'mt.exe -manifest program.exe.manifest client.manifest -out:program.exe.manifest'

However, when I run the program I'm getting an message box that says ' Run-time error -2147220999 (800401f9): Automation error , Error in the Dll'

Am i doing things correctly above, anyone had similar experience, any help appreciated.

Comment: A [ComVisible] .NET assembly requires the `<clrClass>` element in the manifest.  A VB6 tool won't know how to do that.  The best way to merge manifests is with a text editor.  And writing one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eew13bza%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a short description how [UMMM](https://github.com/wqweto/UMMM) does it:

1. First, for the .Net dll it generates a manifest to a temp file with this

   ```
   mt.exe -nologo -managedassemblyname:"{dotnet_dll}" -nodependency -out:"{dotnet_dll}.manifest"
   ```
2. Then embeds this manifest into .Net dll as RT_MANIFEST resource 2 with this

   ```
   mt.exe -nologo -manifest "{dotnet_dll}.manifest" -outputresource:"{dotnet_dll}";2
   ```
3. Finally references the .Net dll from the VB6 executable by extracting `assemblyIdentity` tag from .Net dll manifest and adding it to the reg-free manifest inside `dependency\dependentAssembly` tag like this

   ```
   <dependency>
       <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="PdfSigner" version="1.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="msil" />
       </dependentAssembly>
   </dependency>
   ```

This way `clrClass` tags Hans mentions appear in the the .Net dll embedded manifest and not in the VB6 executable manifest.

Comment: Hi wqw, now the program.exe manifest seems to pick up the Client.dll embedded manifest. 

But now I get an error in a message box appear thats says: Run-time error '-2146234341' (8013101b) Automation error.

So I thought it might be the client.dll code related problem but when I do a regasm with the Client.dll the program.exe works.

The com Client.dll uses and references 2 other .net dlls, .A.dll and a B.dll which also sits in the same directory as the program.exe. 

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you put the Net dll's the Client.dll depends on in the same folder as the *VB6 executable*? The error you have almost certainly is a simple path finding error. Use fuslogvw.exe (from the windows7.1 SDK) and sxstrace.exe to troubleshoot this.