# Is it possible to create a manifest file for a VB6 application which references a C# .DLL, so that the .DLL does not have to be registered?

Tags: c#, .net, vb6, com-interop

Is it possible to create a manifest file for a VB6 application which references a C# .DLL, so that the .DLL does not have to be registered?

I do this with VB6 com dlls with no issues.
Can it be done when using .net .dlls if so how?

The C# .dll is com visible and works fine ren registered, but I need to distribute it to X number of machines.

Comment: [How to: Configure .NET Framework-Based COM Components for Registration-Free Activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/configure-net-framework-based-com-components-for-reg)

Comment: The procedure is not fundamentally different from vb6 dlls.  You have to use clrclass instead of comclass, google "clrclass manifest" for basic hits.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755426/how-do-i-create-a-manifest-file-in-visual-basic-6-0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Including .NET assemblies in a VB6 manifest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164660/including-net-assemblies-in-a-vb6-manifest)